# Ошибка HRESULT: 0x80131040 при создании миграции

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, macos, visual-studio-2017

когда я делаю миграцию выдаёт такую ошибку:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   '/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.101/DotnetTools/dotnet-ef/2.2.0/tools/netcoreapp2.2/any/tools/netcoreapp2.0/any/ef.dll'.
>   The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

что делать?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш файл csproj (секция с пакетами), покажите вывод `dotnet -info` и напишите какие SDK ставили и если обновляли то чем. И вообще неплохо бы указать, что у вас - дебиан/центос/чтотамещёизподдерживаемыхплатформ.

Comment: Ох, ну и чехарда с версиями... Выровняйте все версии для начала к 2.2.101 раз у вас установлен 2.2.х (а вообще `dotnet -info` тоже неплохо бы показать)

Comment: а как  вообще полностью удалить эти версий ?

Comment: Не понимаю вопрос. Давайте наугад две версии ответа: а) закройте проект или даже лучше всю студию, откройте на редактирование csproj и поменяйте все записи в файле на одно и то же число б) скажите что у вас за линукс и что находится в `/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/`

Comment: у меня mac os .

Comment: Я с маками не работал, поэтому вряд ли могу какие-то конкретные платформоспецифичные рекомендации дать.

Comment: зачем удалять...просто версии поставьте из `nuget`